# Many threads created using C3P0 with Hibernate/Spring

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate, c3p0

I do a project merging Hibernate and Spring in a Java web application, using Tomcat under Linux environment. Due to the Mysql 8 hours timeout problem, we want to use C3P0 to manage a connection pool with our Mysql database.
But when we use it, we have numerous threads that are created. I figured it out beacause I did on each request a print of all of them with a memory status that show me the increasing memory  and that kind of threads:

> - name: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hged7o8r13kpj7n1h3ycia|39c446]-HelperThread-#0   daemon: true   group! main   groupParent: system   alive: true   interrupted: false
> - name: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hged7o8r13kpj7n1h3ycia|17ec0e8]-AdminTaskTimer   daemon: true   group! main   groupParent: system   alive: true   interrupted: false

It can produce more than 500 threads like these ones, after enough time.

Here is my Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <property name="connection.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myBase</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">myProject</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>

    <property name="cache.provider_class">
      org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
    </property>
```

I also tried to add a C3P0 propeties file, but except reducing the helper thread number, it don't delete the unsused thread:

```
    c3p0.maxStatements=5    

c3p0.maxIdleTime=10

c3p0.numHelperThreads=1

c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1

c3p0.initialPoolSize=1
c3p0.minPoolSize=1
c3p0.maxPoolSize=10

c3p0.acquireIncrement=1
c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=1
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this happen and how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found a combination of properties to solve my problem, keeping in mind that I don't need a lot of connection at a time:

- c3p0.maxStatements=5
- c3p0.maxIdleTime=10
- c3p0.numHelperThreads=3
- c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
- c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1
- c3p0.initialPoolSize=1
- c3p0.minPoolSize=1
- c3p0.maxPoolSize=1
  c3p0.acquireIncrement=1
- c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=1
- c3p0.maxAdministrativeTaskTime=1

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Adding idleConnectionTestPeriod=1 is being way too agressive. I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

if you are seeing a multiplication of c3p0 helper and timer threads, you are somehow creating a multitude of c3p0 DataSources when you want there to be just one. sometimes this happens if you are hot-reloading your app but forgetting to close() your old c3p0 DataSource when you recycle.

effectively it looks like you are "leaking" DataSources. you need to figure out why/where this is happening. for some clues, check out your logs for c3p0 DataSource initialization messages at INFO level. Search for the string "Initializing c3p0 pool", for example.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to create a number of threads proportional to `c3p0.minPoolSize`
and `c3p0.maxPoolSize` and your maximum is 10.

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#other_ds_configuration
"**numHelperThreads** and maxAdministrativeTaskTime help to configure the behavior of DataSource thread pools. **By default, each DataSource has only three associated helper threads**. If performance seems to drag under heavy load, or if you observe via JMX or direct inspection of a PooledDataSource, that the number of "pending tasks" is usually greater than zero, try increasing numHelperThreads. maxAdministrativeTaskTime may be useful for users experiencing tasks that hang indefinitely and "APPARENT DEADLOCK" messages. (See Appendix A for more.) "

numHelperThreads defines how many threads per DataSource are used, therefore indeed you will have 10 threads with `numHelperThreads=1`.

The only way to make sure C3P0 consumes only one Thread is to set  `c3p0.minPoolSize`
and `c3p0.maxPoolSize` to 1 but this defeats the purpose of connection pooling.

Comment: If i set "c3p0.numHelperThreads=0", my request never ends, and by default the value is 3.

Comment: You can try but I would expect something not to work, I would expect these threads to monitor the status of the connections for you, and maybe do more.

Comment: I tried with "c3p0.numHelperThreads=3" and "c3p0.maxAdministrativeTaskTime=10" and nothing changed

Comment: you just **increased** the number of threads. Remember it will kick off the connections and threads depending on the load. If you just initialize it without any workload (creating many connections etc) then it might not start them.

Comment: hi, there's a bit of a mistake here. numHelperThreads is the number of Threads created _per DataSource_, not per Connection. numHelperThreads=1 is usually not so good an idea.